# Group and sum data based on a day of the month

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a reoccurring payment day of `14th` of each month and want to group a subset of data by month/year and sum the sent column. For example for the given data:-

```
Table `Counter`
Id   Date         Sent 
1    10/04/2013     2      
2    11/04/2013     4      
3    15/04/2013     7 
4    10/05/2013     3      
5    14/05/2013     5      
6    15/05/2013     3 
7    16/05/2013     4
```

The output I want is something like:

```
From         Count
14/03/2013    6
14/04/2013    10
14/05/2013    12
```

I am not worried how the from column is formatted or if its easier to split into month/year as I can recreated a date from multiple columns in the GUI. So the output could easily just be:

```
FromMth   FromYr         Count
03         2013           6
04         2013          10
05         2013          12
```

or even

```
toMth       toYr         Count
04         2013           6
05         2013          10
06         2013          12
```

If the payment date is for example the `31st` then the date comparison would need to be the last date of each month. I am also not worried about missing months in the result-set.

I will also turn this into a `Stored procedure` so that I can push in the the payment date and other filtered criteria. It is also worth mentioning that we can go across years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
select  
if(day(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m")) >= 14, 
   concat('14/', month(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m")), '/', year(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m"))) , 
   concat('14/', if ((month(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m")) - 1) = 0, 
                     concat('12/', year(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m")) - 1),
                     concat(month(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m"))-1,'/',year(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%d-%m")))
                    )
         )

  ) as fromDate, 
sum(sent)
from tbl
group by  fromDate
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbd0/10)**

```
|   FROMDATE | SUM(SENT) |
--------------------------
| 14/10/2013 |         3 |
| 14/12/2012 |         1 |
|  14/3/2013 |         6 |
|  14/4/2013 |        10 |
|  14/5/2013 |        12 |
|  14/9/2013 |         1 |
```

Comment: That query will break at the beginning of year. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94bdb/1

Comment: The fiddle works, BUT for some reason fromdate for data i am testing this against comes back as null...

Comment: It must be the problem of formatting the date. The fiddle took date in the format of `yyyy-dd-mm` and mysql understands in format of `yyyy-mm-dd`, but better go for Gordon's solution it is simple...

Comment: yes looks like it, sorry my date is stored as 2013-04-28 13:54:32 etc

Comment: Yes...  You have to just change the format that I have mentioned in the `str_to_date` function to one which you are using.... Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 for helping, need to work out business logic with client to see how we proceed with 31 day months and going back 1 month as there will be duplicate counts...

Comment: Perfect, this one works as intended when I have a re-occurrence day of 31. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pay date could be grouped by months and year separatedly

```
    select Sum(Sent) as "Count",
           Extract(Month from Date - 13) as FromMth,
           Extract(Year from Date - 13) as FromYr
      from Counter
  group by Extract(Year from Date - 13),
           Extract(Month from Date - 13)
```

Be careful, since field's name "Date" coninsides with the keyword "date" in ANSISQL

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do what you want is to just subtract 14 days rom the date and group by that month:

```
select date_format(date - 14, '%Y-%m'), sum(sent)
from counter
group by date_format(date - 14, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: I will test it but what happens if a month has 31 days and reoccurring date is on the 31st....

Comment: @Rippo . . . That would be a different problem.  If the recurring date is the last date of the month, then I would not subtract any days at all.